# Delete folder with large number of files

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

I want to delete a folder with large number of files (>100.000).

I only have FTP access. No SSH.

Do you have any ideas how to run commands via Terminal to delete? It seems to be impossible to do it with Filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

You may use one of these console based ftp-clients:

General Unix:
[NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com)

Debian /Redhat:
[yafc](http://www.stacken.kth.se/~mhe/yafc/)

Windows:
Just use the built in cmd and type:

```
ftp -?  //for available commands

delete remote__file_name //for file deletion

rmdir directory_name //for dir deletion
```